# for loop is not being executed python

Tags: python, execution

When I run my program, a certain part of the code is not being executed:

```
for d in range(0, n+m-1, -1):
    cur = ""
    print("a")
for x in range(max(0, d-m+1),min(n, d+1),-1):
    cur = letras[x][d-x] + cur
    print(cur)
```

The `print()` instructions are never being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `n+m-1` is greater than 0, a step value of `-1` will create an empty range. For example, `print(list(range(0, 2, -1)))` outputs `[]`.

So check your input or wherever `n` and `m` are coming from.

Of course, same is true for the second `range`. Make sure that `min(n, d+1)` is **not** greater than `max(0, d-m+1)`.

Consult `range` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).